# VBA Excel - Using Substring to get Buyer

Tags: excel, vba, substring

I am writing a VBA Excel code, and I need to extract the BUYER from the following transaction.

Sample Transaction

```
1) Peter sell 10 apples to May
2) Jon sell 3 pears to Wei Liang
3) Tom sell to William 4 oranges
4) Ellen sell 1 banana to Andy
```

Who is the Buyer

```
1) May
2) Wei Liang
3) William
4) Andy
```

I have no control over the Transaction I receive.
As you can see, Number 3 format is a bit different.
The only thing similar is that Buyer always comes after the word "to"

```
Public Sub Populate_FullData()

Dim TransArray() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim id As String
Dim pos As Integer

' Populate TranArray() with the 4 Transactions
....
'

For i = LBound(TransArray) To UBound(TransArray)
id = "to"
pos = InStr(TransArray, id)
**I am stuck here on how to continue**
End Sub
```

Any suggestions is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `365`, you may be able to do this with worksheet formula:
*I note that the buyer is not only preceded by a `to` but in some cases it is followed by a by a digit*

```
=LET(ta,TEXTAFTER(A2,"to "),TEXTBEFORE(ta,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},1,,,ta))
```

[image]

If you don't have `365`, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.

```
let
//change next lines to reflect actual data source and column header
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Transaction", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Buyer", each 
        Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({" "},{"0".."9"})
        (Text.Split([Transaction],"to "){1}){0}, type text)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Fine & instructive +:)

Comment: Thank you. My transactions are given as a Textfile. I see if can load into Excel and do your method

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `Application.Match()` method:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Populate_FullData()
    
    ' Populate TranArray() with the 4 Transactions
   
        
    ' loop TranArray()
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(TransArray) To UBound(TransArray)
        
            Dim transItem As Variant
                transItem = Split(TransArray(i), " ") ' this gives you an array of the strings delimited by a blank in the transaction
                
                Dim id As String
                    id = "to"
                Dim pos As Variant
                    pos = Application.Match(id, transItem, 0)
                    If IsError(pos) Then
                        MsgBox "Cannot spot the buyer in transaction'" & TransArray(i) & "'"
                    Else
                        MsgBox "The buyer of transaction '" & TransArray(i) & "' is : " & transItem(pos)
                    End If
        Next
    
End Sub
```

Still, there remains the same Wei Liang issue @Derby9421 already told you about
You could handle it by locating a number and deciding w

Answer (score 0):

I used `trim` (sth simpler maybe) "try" to achieve what you need, there's some constraints, e.g. only print the first word after 'to' to identify the buyer, which doesn't include a full name, i.e. for (2), printed Wei instead of Wei Liang. However, it allows to kick off, see the snippet and screenshot as below, hope it help.

```vb
Sub get_buyer()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim transaction As String
    Dim buyer As String
    Dim startPos As Integer
    Dim endPos As Integer
    
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each cell In rng
        transaction = cell.Value
        
        startPos = InStr(1, transaction, "to")
        
        If startPos > 0 Then
            startPos = startPos + 3
            endPos = InStr(startPos, transaction, " ")
            
            If endPos > 0 Then
                buyer = Trim(Mid(transaction, startPos, endPos - startPos))
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = buyer
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Transaction notes are in Column A, make amendments accordingly.

Results looks like,

[image]

#### Alternative option

Had another thought to be bit sophisticated. It should identify buyer's name from the transaction string. It first splits the string into words, then it checks each word to see if it is "to". If it is, it assumes that this is the buyer's name and returns it. If the next word is not capitalised, it assumes that the buyer's name is only one word long and returns it. If the word "to" is not found in the string, it returns an empty string.

[image]

Still it's not perfect as you can see example 3, should be read as _William" instead of *William 4* despite you can flag it for later correction. As am not on Windows and *Regular Expression Library* is not my option. See the snippet below may help,

```vb
Sub ExtractBuyer()
   Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim transaction As String
    Dim buyer As String
     
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each cell In rng
        transaction = cell.Value
        buyer = ExtractBuyerName(transaction)
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = buyer
    Next cell
End Sub

Function ExtractBuyerName(transaction As String) As String
    Dim words() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim buyerName As String
    
    words = Split(transaction, " ")
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(words)
        If words(i) = "to" Then
            buyerName = words(i + 1)
            If i + 2 <= UBound(words) Then
                If IsCapitalized(words(i + 2)) Then
                    buyerName = buyerName & " " & words(i + 2)
                End If
            End If
            ExtractBuyerName = buyerName
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
    ExtractBuyerName = ""
End Function

Function IsCapitalized(ByVal text As String) As Boolean
    If Len(text) > 0 Then
        IsCapitalized = UCase(Left(text, 1)) = Left(text, 1)
    Else
        IsCapitalized = False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub get_buyer()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim transaction As String
     
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each cell In rng
        transaction = parse(cell.Value)
        cell.Offset(0, 4) = transaction
    Next cell
End Sub

Public Function parse(inpPat As String)
      Dim regexOne1 As Object
      Dim theMatches As Object
      Dim Match As Object
      Dim Result As String: Result = ""

      Set regexOne1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'New RegExp
      regexOne1.Global = True
      regexOne1.IgnoreCase = True
      regexOne1.MultiLine = True
      regexOne1.Pattern = "(to )\w+([ a-zA-Z]+)"
   
      Set theMatches = regexOne1.Execute(inpPat)

      For Each Match In theMatches
            res = Match.Value
            Result = Replace(res, "to ", "")
      Next
      parse = Result
    End Function
```

The result is [image]

Answer (score 0):

A further option would be the following procedere writing all data entries to a datafield array (`data`) allowing to extract buyers via function `getBuyer()`, write them back to the array and write the whole datafield back to range:

- split all data entries by the defined delimiter "to "
- split the right part into single elements
- concatenate these elements until you find a **numeric** value indicating the end of name elements; *otherwise you'd get `"William 4 oranges"` in the 3rd data entry instead of `"William"`.*

**Example call**

```
Sub ExampleCall()
With Tabelle3.Range("A2:A5")               ' define individual range
    Dim data: data = .Value2               ' write range data to datafield
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)              ' loop thru data (row entries)
        data(i, 1) = getBuyer(data(i, 1))  ' overwrite initial entries
    Next i
    .Offset(, 1).Value2 = data             ' write results to target range
End With
End Sub
```

```
Function getBuyer(ByVal elem As Variant) As String
'Purp: concatenate each elem after "to ", but stop before numeric values
    For Each elem In elems(elem)           ' get array of elems after "to "
        If IsNumeric(elem) Then Exit For   ' stop concatenation before nums
        getBuyer = getBuyer & " " & elem   ' return buyer
    Next
End Function
```

```
Function elems(ByVal s As String)
'Purp: return array of split elems after "to "
    Const DELIM As String = "to "          ' define constant delimiter "to "
    Dim rightPart As String
    rightPart = Split(s & DELIM, DELIM)(1) ' get right part after delimiter
    elems = Split(rightPart)               ' return array of elements
End Function
```

*Hint to `rightPart = Split(s & DELIM, DELIM)(1)`: The additional `DELIM` attached to the string input `s` is a tricky way to avoid hypothetical errors getting the second (right) string part if there would be no "to "-delimiter at all.*

[image: Result]