# Excel VBA - Error 2029 | LET formula shown as #Name?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to reference to my previous post here:
[VBA Excel - Using Substring to get Buyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77674246/vba-excel-using-substring-to-get-buyer)

In Summary, I want to get the buyer.

Sample Transactions

```
1) Peter sell 10 apples to May
2) Jon sell 3 pears to Wei Liang
3) Tom sell to William 4 oranges
4) Ellen sell 1 banana to Andy
```

I am using VBA code to enter the LET formula into the cell. The code will add the formula to read the Transaction, then remove the formula from the cell as soon below:

```
'Get Buyer with TextAfter/Before
        id = "to"
        Set BuyerCell = Cells(rowNo, colNo + 10)    'Temp Cell to get Buyer
        BuyerCell.Value = "=LET(ta,TEXTAFTER(" & fd_sellAddress(i) & "," & DQ & id & DQ & "),TEXTBEFORE(ta,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},1,,,ta))"
        buyer = StrConv(Trim(BuyerCell.Value), vbProperCase)
        BuyerCell.Value = ""
```

The value of DQ is just two quotes

```
Public Const DQ As String = """"
```

fd_sellAddress(i) is the Cell Address of the Transaction. So if the Transaction is at Cell A2, fd_sellAddress(i) is $A$2.

When I run the Macro, the cell is showing "#Name?" and I get Error 2029.

By the way, when I run the code, the cell looks like this:

```
=@LET(ta,TEXTAFTER($A$2,"to"),TEXTBEFORE(ta,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},1,,,ta))
```

Even if I plainly copy the formula and paste in the cell without running VBA, I still get same error.

The thing is about 1 month ago when I run this code, it works. But no idea why it doesn't work now. Any idea? Previously I was using 365 Family, now I am using MS 365 Personal. I think it's silly if that's the reason.

Much Appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `BuyerCell.Value = ` use `BuyerCell.Formula2 = ` to write your formula to the sheet. This is necessary as you are using a `LET`- formula.

Comment: @Ike - OP said "Even if I plainly copy the formula and paste in the cell without running VBA, I still get same error."

Comment: Use an explicit reference to `Cells` by adding the parent sheet before eg. `Sheet1.cells`

Comment: Why do it this way instead of directly in VBA?

Comment: Is your Personal version earlier than the Family version you were using? The documentation states the LET function applies to "Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Excel for the web Excel 2021 Excel 2021 for Mac"

Comment: What is the name of the worksheet? Is this code in the same workbook as the worksheet? Please share the complete code to receive reasonable solutions i.e. a pure VBA solution as suggested by Ron Rosenfeld (recommended) or a continuation down the path you took (not recommended). BTW, you could also evaluate the formula instead of writing it to a temporary cell, e.g. `Buyer = StrConv(Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("LET(ta,TEXTAFTER(" & fd_sellAddress(i) & "," & DQ & id & DQ & "),TEXTBEFORE(ta,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},1,,,ta))")), vbProperCase)`.